# How to use Angular5 for checking muiltiple variables with *ngIf?

Tags: angular5

I am using angular 5 and I'm trying to check the value of list of variables in the html template of the component.

```
<div *ngIf="item=='none'">
      <li>item : "none"</li>
     <li>item 1 : "recipe-book"</li>
</div>
```

For number of items I have to check whether its value is none or some what.So how to check with key of number of lists(item,item1)

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "lists(item,item1)"?
Is it an indexed array?
lists[0] = item1,
lists[1] = item2 ..etc? @A.JRJ

Comment: please share the code in **ts** of the component and explain what u  want to do